# How can I change the user access permission (read write mode for different user) using drupal and civicrm?

Tags: drupal, permissions

I want to set a different values for different users(Read/write permission) by using php **not by a customizing** (Drupal menu - > People -> permission).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are interested in CiviCRM permissions rather than Drupal content, take a look at [the Hooks section in the Developer guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/), specifically the Permission Hooks subsection.

Comment: I am using drupal as CMS. Depending upon user login, it should show the data depending upon user role.How can I match the CMS and CRM user?

Comment: In that case, take a look at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/group-roles/ to sync between a Drupal Role and CiviCRM Group